# Focus Does Not Work for React Native TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a multiline textinput that I want to focus to in the `onComponentDidMount` function. If I just set the `autoFocus` prop to 'true' instead, then everything works fine. But If I want to focus manually, via `this.refs.myRefName.focus()`, I get an error that informs me that that is not a function. However, I've used this previously in React Native to its desired effect (I'm currently using v0.36.0). So, how do you manually focus a textinput now?

Comment: on which OS are you testing this?

Comment: I created a minimal example using RN v.0.34.1. Toggling focus on a multiline `TextInput` with the press of a button or on component mount worked flawlessly. Could you post some code? Are you sure you are using `componentDidMount` and not `onComponentDidMount`?

Comment: Ok, after dabbling around a bit, it turns out that if you have a text input that you made animated via `Animated.createAnimatedComponent`, the blur/focus causes a function does not exist error on the ref of the text input. This is a bug that should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Autofocus now works on android with this pull request [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/23143) does't need to call focus() function in componentDidMound. only set autoFocus={true} enough.